# Bing Maps default pushpins are offset on map

Tags: bing-maps

Ok, so I'm having to use Bing Maps for a client, and I'm having issues with default pushpins.

When I add pushpins and set enableHoverStyle = true, it appears that the pushpin is below the mouseover area by 1.5 times the height of the pushpin.

So when the map renders and pins are added, the pushpin doesn't display the hover state unless the mouse is fairly high above the pin.

Here's an image of the issue: [http://imgur.com/a/fzT54](https://imgur.com/a/fzT54)

Is there any way to get the hover area to accurately position over the pin?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this behavior. Can you try the following sample and see if it reproduces for you there: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#setPushpinOptions+JS

If it doesn't then there is likely something in your application causing an issue. Could you provide a small sample that reproduces your issue.